# Is there a way to AsyncStorage.getItem in this.state?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

The problem is that I could do `setState`, but it only works **after** `ComponmentDidMount()`. For example, when I put `this.state.name` in the fetch URL (`http://www.example.com/list.php?name=${name}`)It doesn't regonize what `name` is until I put it into the `constructor()`. If it's not possible to put AsyncStorage in `this.state` without `this.setState` then how do I fix this problem?

```
    constructor(props)
{

  super(props);

  this.state = {
  isLoading: true,
  name: 'hey'
}
}

componentDidMount() {

  AsyncStorage.getItem("name").then((value) => {
    this.setState({"name": value});
})

      return fetch(`http://www.example.com/list.php?name=${this.state.name}` , {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function myFunc() {
  
  var name = await AsyncStorage.getItem('name');

  return fetch(`http://www.example.com/list.php?name=` + name , {
           method: 'POST',
           headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           }
}

componentDidMount(){
 this.myFunc();
}
```